# How to update a variable with different string values in the same method using java?

Tags: java

Could some one please advise with the below?

```
private String dataName;
private String sourceType;

public void getConnectionData(){
    DataCollector data = new DataCollector();
    portNumber = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, dataName);
    channel  = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, dataName);
    hostName = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, dataName);    
    queueName = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, dataName);
    queueManager = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, dataName);

}
```

I have the above method, I am trying to make dataName equal the below for each of the above when I am trying to use the method from the other class.

```
    dataName = "portNumber";    
    dataName = "channel";   
    dataName = "hostName";  
    dataName = "queueName"; 
    dataName = "queueManager";
```

Could someone please advise how i go about it?

Thanks

Comment: hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: I think it's superfluous to make such abstraction, just use different String constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not the usual:

```
portNumber = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, "portNumber");
channel  = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, "channel");
hostName = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, "hostName");    
queueName = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, "queueName");
queueManager = data.getConnectionData(sourceType, "queueManager");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was curious that if I did this using the method getConnectionData(String source,String dataName) in the  DataCollector class wont work but I will test it out. I am very new to java so I am not sure on what things work and what wont